# use jQuery/jQuerymobile .text to set content of multiple id's

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a page with multiple page(s- data-roles), and want to set the content on div's, or other elements. Basically this works... like this:

```
<a href="..something" id="content-something"></a>
<div id="content-sometext"></div>
```

and setting it with that:

```
$('#content-something').text('Something in there');
$('#content-sometext').text('Sometext in there');
```

The problem occurs when I try to set the content over multiple instances of the id's, and only the first id is being set - whether in the same page- data role or not:

```
<a href="..something" id="content-something"></a> ---> Something in there
<div id="content-sometext"></div> ---> Sometext in there
Some more html...
<a href="..something" id="content-something"></a> ---> empty!
<div id="content-sometext"></div> ---> empty!
```

As far as I understood the jQuery/mobile documentation, multiple instances should be able to be set with .text().

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks a lot for your help in advance :)

Comment: That's why IDs must be unique on context page. Use class instead. But as a workaround for really bad coding, you can use: $('[id=content-something]')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is an expected behavior as IDs are suppose to be unique. Use class name to replace text of multiple elements.

```
<a href="..something" class="content-something"></a>
<div class="content-sometext"></div>
Some more html...
<a href="..something" class="content-something"></a>]
<div class="content-sometext"></div>
```